# Why does ISNULL generate no "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation." but CASE IS NULL and COALESCE do?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had this that generated a "Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation." warning:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN prix_unitaire IS NULL OR qte_vendues IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE prix_unitaire * qte_vendues END)
        FROM facturation_detail AS fdp
        WHERE fdp.id_facturation_detail_parent = fd.id_facturation_detail) AS prix_groupe
FROM facturation_detail AS fd
WHERE id_facturation_entete = '1AB10ADA-58F9-EA11-84FF-D4AE526DD012'
```

I changed it to this, but it still generated a warning:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(COALESCE(prix_unitaire * qte_vendues, 0))
        FROM facturation_detail AS fdp
        WHERE fdp.id_facturation_detail_parent = fd.id_facturation_detail) AS prix_groupe
FROM facturation_detail AS fd
WHERE id_facturation_entete = '1AB10ADA-58F9-EA11-84FF-D4AE526DD012'
```

Changing it to this finally got rid of the warning, but I don't understand why this third query got rid of the warning but not the previous two:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(prix_unitaire, 0) * ISNULL(qte_vendues, 0))
        FROM facturation_detail AS fdp
        WHERE fdp.id_facturation_detail_parent = fd.id_facturation_detail) AS prix_groupe
FROM facturation_detail AS fd
WHERE id_facturation_entete = '1AB10ADA-58F9-EA11-84FF-D4AE526DD012'
```

Can someone explain why the first two generate the warning, but not the last one? prix_unitaire and qte_vendues are of types decimal(10, 4) and decimal(8, 2) respectively, both allowing NULL values, in case that's relevant.

EDIT: The only rows I have into facturation_detail that have id_facturation_entete = '1AB10ADA-58F9-EA11-84FF-D4AE526DD012' are the following three:

```
id_facturation_entete|id_facturation_detail|id_facturation_detail_parent|prix_unitaire|qte_vendues
1AB10ADA-58F9-EA11-84FF-D4AE526DD012|1BB10ADA-58F9-EA11-84FF-D4AE526DD012|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000|25.5000|1.00
1AB10ADA-58F9-EA11-84FF-D4AE526DD012|1CB10ADA-58F9-EA11-84FF-D4AE526DD012|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000|47.8400|1.00
1AB10ADA-58F9-EA11-84FF-D4AE526DD012|1DB10ADA-58F9-EA11-84FF-D4AE526DD012|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000|47.8400|1.00
```

EDIT: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

EDIT: A screenshot of the execution plan for the first and third queries (the first and second have the same execution plan):

[image]

Comment: All of this query when copy paste to this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=50b8635a9d049a20c6f2e1292edc0dbf do not produce warning or error. Can you simulate your error ?

Comment: @VBoka I'm not getting the warning on the fiddle, but then again, I have SQL Server Management Studio 2012 on Linux at home, which isn't amongst the options on the fiddle.

Comment: @VBoka Moreover, the fiddle has no rows inserted...

Comment: Hi @MickaelBergeronNéron please do insert them, and add it to your comment...

Comment: @VBoka I'm at work, so I can't invest the time for this right now, but I'll do later today.

Comment: I don't know whether dbfiddle.uk merely supresses warning. I've also read that you must have `SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON` to see such messages. Anyway, it seems that this message means that aggregate functions don't consider nulls, which is how they are defined, so I'd consider this warning completely pointless.

Comment: These warnings make some sense. Say you AVG(income), but only 10 % have that value. Then the AVG() warning indicates your data lacks some values - perhaps you should take a closer look at what your result really means.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner dbfiddle doesn't suppress those warnings. You'll get them if you do a straight `SELECT SUM(prix_unitaire * qte_vendues) FROM facturation_detail` and one of the rows contains a null prix_unitaire or null qte_vendues value.

Comment: @VBoka I updated the first query in the fiddle, but I don't know how to share the updated fiddle. I am not getting any warning on the fiddle however. Here's the insert I added after the query:

insert into facturation_detail(prix_unitaire, qte_vendues,
id_facturation_detail_parent, id_facturation_detail,
       id_facturation_entete) values (2, 3, 100, 101, 'FABD0A3A-5899-EA5B-84AF-D4AE5264C013')

Comment: @VBoka I added details, including a screenshot of the execution plans.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, the first two should *not* generate the error.  As you have written the code, no `NULL` values are passed through to the aggregation.  Only zero is passed in.  Hence, I would consider this a bug, but I'm not so sure that Microsoft agrees.

What I suspect is happening is that SQL Server is optimizing the code by rearranging the operations.  This rearrangement should not affect the results at all (which is why it is allowed).  Well, except that you can get errors and warnings that should not be in the original query.

I don't know why this would be happening in this case.  It sounds like a micro-optimization, where eliminating the some `NULL` comparisons *before* the `sum()` is marginally faster because the `sum()` is checking for `NULL` anyway.

A more common example is that a query like this can generate an error:

```
select 1 / x
from t
where x <> 0;
```

SQL Server can rearrange the operations so the division occurs before the filtering.

Comment: it appears to be how case & coalesce are evaluated when in aggregates...https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression

Comment: @lptr . . . I didn't see anything in that article that explains this.  In the first two queries, the `case`/`coalesce()` *cannot* return a `NULL` value.  The "premature" evaluation of paths occurs when there is an aggregation function as part of the `case` expression -- which is not the case here (and that has to do with how aggregation functions are calculated).  Perhaps I missed something, though.

Comment: ....bug in Connect #690017 : CASE / COALESCE won't always evaluate in textual order;....

Comment: @lptr . . . I am quite aware of that.  If you look at the bug, it is about aggregation functions in the `when` part -- and that is not relevant to this question.  It is considered "by design" because the aggregation functions and case semantics are "competing" for the same space in a sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added a screenshot of the execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning, a reminder, that NULL is "ignored" in aggregations. Aggregate functions do not consider NULL at all.
All three following statements will give back the warning:

```
select sum(val)
from 
(values (1), (2), (null), (null)) as t(val);

select max(val)
from 
(values (1), (2), (null), (null)) as t(val);

select min(val)
from 
(values (1), (2), (null), (null)) as t(val);
```

When ISNULL(, 0) is used, NULL goes away and the aggregate function operates on a value, i.e 0. The same, happens with CASE when it always returns a value(not null):

```
--no warning
select sum(isnull(val, 0))
from 
(values (1), (2), (null), (null)) as t(val);


select sum(case when a is null or b is null then 0 else a*b end)
from 
(values (1, 1), (2, null), (null, null), (null, 3)) as t(a, b);
```

You could safely ignore the warning, unless you did not expect NULL values in the aggregation and you have the warning as a reminder for that.

Caution: isnull(, 0) will change the result for most of the aggregates and more often than not it is unnecessary:

```
select min(val), min(isnull(val, 0)) 
from 
(values (1), (2), (null), (null)) as t(val);
```

Comment: I know that, but that does not answer the question, which is "why do the first two give the warning but not the third one?".

Comment: is facturation_detail a table or a view?

Comment: Is there a fk (self reference) from detail_parent--> detail?

Comment: There are none.

Comment: Actually, there are, but none which also have id_facturation_entete = 'FABD0A3A-5899-EA5B-84AF-D4AE5264C013'

Comment: I did many more tests, and at this point, I suspect a [minor] bug with SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Comment: you could check the execution plan and see what goes in the aggregate operator (is it a stream or hash aggregate)? Besides the sum() there could also be a count_big() calculated...check that one too.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the execution plan. It is a stream aggregate. I don't see any count_big() calculated. Interestingly, the execution plans differ a fair bit between the first two queries and the third one.